# Threejs hex color difference

Tags: javascript, three.js

When creating the material I'm using the hex 0x205081, like this:

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x205081, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});

After changing a few colors in the faces, I try to change them back to the original color (0x205081), but it's apparently darker than when first initialized, even using the exact same hex code, what am I missing?

The difference can be noticed on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/4805/

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add(camera);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x205081, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}); 

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
       geometry.faces.map(function(f) {
          f.color.setHex( 0x205081);
    });
    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506997/superimposing-of-color/27737708#27737708, which is the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful the color of MeshBasicMaterial is not the same as the color of the faces.

What you want is this:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene.add(camera);

    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);

    //Set material to white color so it doesn't conflict when applying actual face colors
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}); 

    //Set your initial face colors like this, not with material
    geometry.faces.map(function(f) {
          f.color.setHex( 0x205081);
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}

function render() {

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    geometry.faces.map(function(f) {
          f.color.setHex( 0x205081);
    });
    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't behave as expected, if I use an image color picker on a screenshot it returns me #041941 instead of #205081.
http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/

Comment: @onionfeelings Is that related to lighting, shading, etc. of the scene?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I assume not, since I'm not setting anything, if you test a screenshot with a hex color picker (ex: http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/)
You'll see that the color set by the material it's ok (#205081) and the one set with by setting the face color is actually #041941.

Comment: @onionfeelings Hmm not sure how accurate sampling a screenshot it. I did a side by side comparison with a rectangle created with the same hex code in my image software and the one rendered on screen. Check it out: http://imgur.com/Hb0QCgf. I think it renders a tad lighter than it should be.

Comment: @onionfeelings Wait a minute, are we seeing the same result in jsfiddle? The 041941 is the color you were seeing in the original example. Here is a jsfiddle example where the initial color is set to something else and switches to 205081 when you click the button. http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/4819/

Comment: @TingSun, your last fiddle actually behaves differently, it sets the right color (205081), I believe you found a workaround to the problem, by setting the initial color to 0xffffff, it's a pitty we don't know why it behaves like that.

Comment: @onionfeelings Been a while since I worked with Three.js, but if I remember correctly MeshMaterial Color will tint textures AND face colors. So basically you can think of MeshMaterial color to add to whatever you set your face color to. In my example I didn't set my initial face color to 0xffffff, I set the MeshMaterial color to 0xffffff so it doesn't modify the face color you set to your cube.